# I can't start Android ported app in Dev Alpha Simulator

Tags: blackberry-simulator, blackberry-android

I have issue with starting an Adroid ported app in BlackBerry Dev Alpha simulator. I have downloaded latest tools from BB Dev site. The app is packaged through Online Packager. I have started the Dev Alpa Simulator as per instructions. The app is installing OK, icon is visible in simulator. However when I click on the app icon it just shows new screen with BlackBerry logo and never loads the app. I have tested with few apps, always the same result.
My computer details:
Intel Pentium B950 @ 2.10GHz
RAM 4.00 GB
NVIDIA GeForce GT 520M

My computer does NOT support hardware virtualization, so the simulator is a bit slow. I have tried to start the simulator with 2 cores and increased the simulator RAM to 2 GB, but the same result - app is not starting.

Additional info: all the apps are running just fine on PlayBook (real device). I have installed the app using the command prompt:
blackberry-tablet-sdk-2.1.0\bin\"blackberry-deploy -installApp

Any help is much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without virtualization on your machine, the Android runtime might take a while to boot. I would suggest running it in safe mode instead. Increasing memory to 2 gigs if possible, helps without virtualization.

Also, instead of just a reset which maintains the same state of the simulator (including the Android runtime), you can enact a full power cycle via the Virtual Machine->Power->Reset option.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the most recent version of the Dev Alpha simulator (10.0.9 beta3), and have you tried restarting it?

Comment: This is the version I use: BlackBerry10Simulator-Installer-BB10_0_09-386-Win-201209241939. Restarted the VM few times.